# sh: epspdf: command not found

Tags: epstopdf

I'm trying to use the `epspdfconversion` package under TeXLive, on a Linux system. I've successfully installed and included said package, but when executing the command:

```
pdflatex MyFile.tex
```

it returns the error:

```
sh: epspdf: command not found
pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file MyImageFile-epspdf-to.pdf): can
not find image file
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I've tried various `pdflatex` options (eg/ `--shell-escape`) with no luck. My guess is that the "command not found" debug points to the problem - any ideas?

---

I've a bit more information: if I try to compile with `latex` (instead of the Makefile I have been using), it produces the output below. I've looked into the file where "\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule" should be defined (tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty) and it is there. It's called by the file tex/latex/epspdfconversion/epspdfconversion.sty, which I include in my top-level .cls file to perform the desired conversions.

Interestingly, if I carriage return through this error a .dvi file is still produced, which can be converted to pdf.

```
Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported.

)

epspdfconversion.sty is using epstopdf.sty with the following setup:
update=true,
verbose=true,
prefersuffix=true,
suffix=-epspdf-to,
option outdir not set. Default: same directory as the .eps-source-file
append,
enable
epspdf is used with the following command:
epspdf <file> 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.345 \epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule
                              {.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Open your terminal and type the following command: `which epspdf` . What does it return?

Comment: "which epspdf" tells me it can't find anything in the usual ../bin/ paths; I expect this since "epspdf" is not an installed program, but rather something that is called on-the-fly by my LaTeX compiler. "epstopdf" works in the terminal, but will this help me with on-the-fly conversions?

Comment: @mamboholly Run `sudo apt-get install texlive-pictures` (see [here](http://packages.debian.org/testing/tex/texlive-pictures) for a description of the package). Use your favorite package manager if you don't want to directly use `apt-get`

Comment: @mamboholly What GNU/Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Linux something.somethingelse 2.6.43.8-1.fc15.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 4 20:33:44 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux Again, sorry for the Answer post - I still don't seem able to comment, perhaps because my posts are unregistered.

Comment: @mamboholly You need to register, if you want to comment. With Fedora it's a bit different, I'll investigate.

Comment: @mamboholly What are you trying to do, really? Using `epspdf` to produce a `.dvi` file doesn't make sense. You have to run `pdflatex`, not `latex`.

Comment: @egreg No I know, I was just trying to coax some more information out of the problem. All I'm trying to do is use `epspdf` with `pdflatex`; if I run `pdflatex --shell-escape MyFile.tex`, where MyFile.tex references an image "MyDir/MyImage.eps", it produces the error `[14]sh: epspdf: command not found
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file MyDir/MyImage-epspdf-to.pdf): can
not find image file
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: This [Fedora Project page](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive) has suggestions about installing missing packages. I usually recommend doing the full install.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I've just removed the epspdf package from my .cls file, and it's now telling me it can't find "X" (where X = path to file), but if I `ls X` it finds it fine...

Answer (score 6):

`epspdf` is a ruby script, its sources can be found [here](http://tex.aanhet.net/epspdf/). For Fedora, there is a `texlive-epspdf` package that should give you that, and usually this should already be installed as a dependency of `texlive`. If not, install that package via your preferred method.

Comment: And for Ubuntu it lives here: `sudo apt install texlive-font-utils`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this other command: `epstopdf` on a bash terminal.

As an alternative you can use graphic programs such as Inkscapeto perform the conversion from eps to pdf files.